# Passing/Piping of multiple output generated from a program into other followed program in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, basically what I am concerned at: I want the search results found by grep to be piped into next program and also use the number of search results done by "wc -l" again in next program itself.

```
**| grep 'logprob' | wc -l | ***Next Code seeking logprob results & size***
```

P.S: grep command is also working on the input files piped to it.

Comment: do you mean you need output of grep as well as word count?

Comment: Well you passed data on stdout to `wc` which in turn consumed it and outputs its output to `stdout`, then when you pass its output further along its the `wc` output that gets passed to the next instance. You will have to save the output from grep into a variable for instance first and the split this to several operations.

Comment: `***Next Code seeking logprob results & size***` , here you'll just have the output of "wc -l".

Comment: @SMA_ True. I want both.

Answer (score 2):

```
... | grep logprob | { tee /dev/stderr | wc -l; } 2>&1 | ...
```

This will write the total number of lines after all the lines have been written, so is not particularly useful (the consuming program will already know the number of lines that it read), but you can use a file:

`... | grep logprob | { tee /tmp/file | wc -l; cat /tmp/file; rm /tmp/file; } | ...`

And now the line count will be the first line available to the consumer.